# Ubuntu 20.04 Can't use GRUB themes

Tags: grub2, themes

No matter what I do, I can't seem to boot with grub themes.

I tried Xenlism and other.

I copied all files from the Theme Folder to `/boot/grub/themes/`.
After running `sudo update-grub`, the commands shows that it recognized the theme, but no theme boots.
I have tried with grub-customizer, and the same happens, nothing.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same trouble when I wanted to update to a HIDPI Grub menu and ended up cloning this repo: https://github.com/vinceliuice/grub2-themes

I then executed the install process for my laptop (Surface Book 2):

```
./install.sh -b -t stylish -s 4k
```

This worked the first time. I did notice that it setup the themes for me in `/usr/share/grub/themes/stylish/theme.txt`

I also tried `grub-customizer` and that didn't work for me either.